# Ansible looping insert

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make ansible loop an insert into a file using a variable in an above debug
In this example i have set "file_limit" to 10, so the debug displays numbers 1-10
I then want to replace "REPLACEME" with 10 rows e.g

```
File_1=file_1.txt
File_2=file_2.txt
...
File_10=file_10.txt
```

My first guess is im not supposed to use replace, but i cant find a method to achieve this

```
- debug:
    var: item
  with_sequence: 1-{{ file_limit }}
  register: foo

- name:
  replace:
    path: "/testing_folder/counter.ini"
    regexp: "REPLACEME"
    loop_var: item
    replace: "File_{{ foo }}=file_{{ foo }}.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playbook below

```
shell> cat counter.ini
REPLACEME
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file_limit: 10
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: counter.ini
        regexp: "^REPLACEME$"
        replace: |
          {% for index in range(1,file_limit+1) %}
          File_{{ index }}=file_{{ index }}.txt
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```
shell> cat counter.ini
File_1=file_1.txt
File_2=file_2.txt
File_3=file_3.txt
File_4=file_4.txt
File_5=file_5.txt
File_6=file_6.txt
File_7=file_7.txt
File_8=file_8.txt
File_9=file_9.txt
File_10=file_10.txt
```